# Deploying FastAPI app to Deta but an error comes up saying sklearn library too large

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deployment, fastapi, requirements.txt

I have a simple machine learning model, it is built with DecisionTreeClassifier from sci-kit learn. I pickled and then pickle-loaded the model into a main.py file, my API app file. I then deployed it locally with FastAPI and tested it with localhost. Everything works well.

I then try to deploy it to Deta. The URL is https://4r8c6b.deta.dev/docs, but it throws an error `Bad Gateway`.

I go to the Deta Visor and check out the error message, and it is copied below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/detalib/debugger.py", line 142, in wrap
    result = func(event, context)
  File "/var/task/_entry.py", line 12, in handler
    import main  # noqa
  File "/var/task/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    stroke_model = pickle.load(open('tree.sav','rb'))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I have only 3 items in my requirements.txt,

```
fastapi
pydantic
scikit-learn
```

I then try `deta deploy` again, and it throws this error in the Terminal,

```
(api) ➜  my_api deta deploy
Updating dependencies...
Error: failed to update dependencies: Request entity too large
```

It looks like the sklearn library is too big to load so that the entire main.py isn't running as lacking proper libraries.

Is there any way to shrink, or only load part of the sklearn library and specify it in `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned before scikit-learn is too big to run in Deta. Deta, as Heroku are designed to run simple or not too heavy API servers.

However, you can run your ML model, using for example BlueTarget. This is a cloud provider focus on deployment of ML model. Let's take a look [here](https://docs.deploy.bluetarget.ai/)